# SQL server table partiton

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I only know the basics of SQL server like create tables, procedures etc. I want to know about table partitioning in SQL server. I would like to get a tutorial which is really simple and easy to understand. I want to know about table partition, index partition ....

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The first [Google Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(SQL.90).aspx) is probably where you'll want to start.

Comment: I hate to sound sarcastic, but it was the first result and it pretty much was an easy to read paper on what the guy asked for...

Comment: At least you didn't use the Let Me Google That For You ;)

Comment: @Konerak: I tried that once.  Stack Overflow actually blocks it from the comments!

Comment: I know. You have to tinyurl it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Partitioned Table and Index Strategies Using SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578580(v=SQL.100).aspx) white paper